# ¿Cómo agregar textbox y datatable dinamicamente? Y que los textbox sean el titulo de las columnas del datatable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, windows-forms

Actualmente tengo un `DataTable` con 4 columnas y 4 cajas de texto las cuales le dan el nombre a las columnas del `DataTable`, a su vez otra caja de texto que le da el nombre a la tabla y una ultima caja de texto donde selecciono los registros a insertar en la instrucción SQL que me genera.

Necesito hacer esto un poco más dinámico, ¿Cómo agregar las cajas de texto que yo desee?. Por ejemplo en una caja de texto ingresar 5, 6, 7, etcetera y esas sean las que se agreguen. Pero además tambien se agreguen columnas al DataTable. Podrían ayudarme ?

Este es mi codigo actual:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Public Partial Class MainForm
    Public Sub New()
        ' The Me.InitializeComponent call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
        Me.InitializeComponent()

        '
        ' TODO : Add constructor code after InitializeComponents
        '
    End Sub

        Dim nombres As String() = {"Aaron","Abel","Abelardo","Abraham","Adalberto","Adolfo","Adrian","Agustin","Alan","Alejandro",
            "Benjamin","Bernardo","Baldomero","Baltasar","Barack", "Josh"}
        Dim apellidos As String() = {"Pineda", "Bernal", "Espinoza", "Spindola", "Brisuela", "Gutierrez", "Escarcega", "Muñiz", "Lopez", "Martinez", "Piña",
            "Vega", "Ortiz", "Barcenas", "Lopez", "Martinez"}
        Dim paises As String() = {"Estados Unidos","Mexico","Costa Rica","Jamaica","Panama","Haiti","Colombia","Venezuela","Ecuador","Peru",
            "Bolivia","Chile","Brasil","Uruguay","Paraguay","Argentina"}


    Sub BtnCrearClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)     
        Const separador = ";"
        Const folder = "C:\Users\desarrollo\Documents\CSV"
        Const titulo = "archivo.csv"
        Dim headers As String() = {txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApp.Text, txtApm.Text}
        Dim filePath = Path.Combine(folder, titulo)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, headers))
        Dim aleatorio As New Random
        For i = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
            Dim fields As String() = {
                i.ToString(),
                nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length)),
                apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,apellidos.Length)),
                paises(aleatorio.Next(0,paises.Length))
            }
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, fields))
        Next
        sw.Close

        'Dim row As DataRow 
        'Dim i As Integer
        'For i = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
            'row=TablaNombres.NewRow()
            'row(txtID.Text)=i
            'If cbo2.SelectedItem = "Nombres" Then
                'row(txtNombre.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
            'ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Apellidos"
                'row(txtNombre.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,apellidos.Length))
            'ElseIf cbo2.SelectedItem = "Paises"
                'row(txtNombre.Text)=paises(aleatorio.Next(0,paises.Length))
            'End If
            'If cbo3.SelectedItem="Nombres" Then
                'row(txtApp.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length)) 
            'ElseIf cbo3.SelectedItem="Apellidos"
                'row(txtApp.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))   
            'ElseIf cbo3.SelectedItem="Paises"
                'row(txtApp.Text)=paises(aleatorio.Next(0, paises.Length))
            'End If
            'If cbo4.SelectedItem="Nombres" Then
                'row(txtApm.Text)=nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
            'ElseIf cbo4.SelectedItem="Apellidos"
                'row(txtApm.Text)=apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
            'ElseIf cbo4.SelectedItem="Paises"
                'row(txtApm.Text)=paises(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length))
            'End If
            'TablaNombres.Rows.Add(row)
        'Next

        'tabla1.DataSource=TablaNombres

        'For i=1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
            'MsgBox("INSERT INTO " & txtTabla.Text & " (" & txtID.Text & ", " & txtNombre.Text & ", " & txtApp.Text & ", " & txtApm.Text & ") VALUES (" & i & ",'" & nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length)) &"','" & apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,apellidos.Length)) &"','" & paises(aleatorio.Next(0,paises.Length)) &"')", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        'Next
    End Sub

    Sub BtnSQLClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Const separador=";"
        Const folder="C:\Users\desarrollo\Documents\CSV"
        Const titulo="archivo.txt"
        'Dim headers As String()={txtID.Text, txtNombre.Text, txtApp.Text, txtApm.Text}
        Dim filePath=Path.Combine(folder, titulo)
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(filePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
        'sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador, headers))
        Dim aleatorio As New Random
        For i=1 To Convert.ToInt32(txtFilas.Text)
            Dim insert As String="INSERT INTO " & txtTabla.Text & " (" & txtID.Text & ", " & txtNombre.Text & ", " & txtApp.Text & ", " & txtApm.Text & ") VALUES (" & i & ",'" & nombres(aleatorio.Next(0,nombres.Length)) &"','" & apellidos(aleatorio.Next(0,apellidos.Length)) &"','" & paises(aleatorio.Next(0,paises.Length)) &"')"
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(separador,insert))
        Next
        sw.Close
    End Sub

    Sub MainFormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim IDColumna As New DataColumn(txtID.Text)
        IDColumna.DataType=GetType(Integer)
        IDColumna.AutoIncrement=True

        Dim Nombre As New DataColumn(txtNombre.Text)
        Nombre.DataType=GetType(String)

        Dim App As New DataColumn(txtApp.Text)
        App.DataType=GetType(String)

        Dim Apm As New DataColumn(txtApm.Text)
        Apm.DataType=GetType(String)

        Dim TablaNombres As New DataTable(txtTabla.Text)
        TablaNombres.Columns.Add(IDColumna)
        TablaNombres.Columns.Add(Nombre)
        TablaNombres.Columns.Add(App)
        TablaNombres.Columns.Add(Apm)

        TablaNombres.Constraints.Add("Key1", IDColumna, True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Para agregar un control en tiempo de ejecución debes:

```
// Crear el control
Dim CajaDB As New TextBox
// Agregarlo al Formulario
Me.Controls.Add(CajaDB)
// Y asignarle las propiedades que desees
CajaDB.Text = "Esta es una caja añadida en tiempo de ejecución"
```

Answer (score 0):

La verdad que no es recomendable la forma en que trabajas en archivo `csv` no se usan las librerias que implementas.

Deberias evaluar librerias como ser

[CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

[FileHelpers](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12170/FileHelpers-v-Delimited-CSV-or-Fixed-Data-Import-E)

para mapear clases con los datos del csv.

Los titulos que mencionas serian las propiedades de la clase que usarias con `List(Of )`, la idea es que trabajes lo mas tipado posible con los datos